# Is there any way to plot face embedding on matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, face-recognition

I am working on `face recognition` project where I have more than `50` face embeddings. These face embeddings are `ndarray` like below:

```
[-0.0200691   0.13491213  0.01145144  0.05688962 -0.00676387  0.19993635
  0.02533266 -0.19400811  0.0411012   0.01464365 -0.00415354  0.05402206
  0.01664302 -0.06064441 -0.03436396 -0.10992181 -0.03958193  0.19097123
 -0.04695265 -0.00612794  0.03623746 -0.01480681 -0.05270521  0.14183706
  0.01199572 -0.07152135 -0.12959275 -0.07721911 -0.03705947  0.14030963
  0.06668457  0.20008644 -0.06984811  0.13318713  0.11428797  0.05426981
  0.05573511 -0.04427484  0.01596998 -0.09757776  0.06715364 -0.15337558
  0.06815095 -0.03429983 -0.04446241 -0.10459255  0.09094309  0.08629964
 -0.11997192  0.04497592  0.09213383 -0.02311416  0.06139569 -0.01395867
  0.07441326  0.12147404 -0.06044842  0.03640871 -0.03004642 -0.0889063
 -0.0301889   0.09588026  0.09767073 -0.23409732  0.09496987  0.01711909
  0.05169532 -0.13107248 -0.24757692  0.2151374  -0.0887977  -0.00853861
 -0.08528605  0.073424   -0.09323349 -0.05573096  0.05621272 -0.03539085
  0.01560351 -0.0991494  -0.08435538  0.15556216 -0.04621118 -0.02670715
 -0.03297476 -0.07187025 -0.02298544 -0.07738702  0.03436666  0.16956662
  0.08456033 -0.12962367  0.11106376 -0.03007854 -0.00976485  0.0348441
 -0.05430228  0.06477121  0.04743555  0.01931698  0.10760706  0.07323861
 -0.10940327  0.09748808  0.06261124  0.03419225 -0.01092734 -0.06298334
 -0.12269804  0.11520871 -0.04536452  0.03717488 -0.0266787  -0.03189107
 -0.01008491 -0.07888404  0.05754598 -0.09802423  0.09052717  0.09657151
  0.15919943 -0.04664587  0.01565368 -0.00321747 -0.02212215  0.04053596
  0.04754856 -0.0818985 ]
```

Is there any way I can plot all the face embedding on `graph` just to visualize how it looks like on graph. Can anyone please suggest some good working solution for this. Thanks

Comment: Is this x, y pairs?

Comment: @david this is 1 ndarry for 1 face image. Didnt get you by x, y pair.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

Your question is equivalent to *"How to mentally visualize a vector in a 128-dimensional vector space?"*. We, humans, can't do this directly.

What you can still do:

- measure the Euclidien distance between two embeddings (128-dimensional vectors) to measure how close two faces are
- do a projection on a 2D or 3D space, and do a plot in this space instead
- have a look at [Principal component analysis (PCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) or similar techniques

---

To answer @david's comment: there is no x, y pair here.